# Shortcode causing white screen of death and breaking my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have added the shortcode to my page template using the function

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[ "shortcode here" ]"); ?>
```

No matter what the shortcode it will break the site. I have another shortocde running before this, is it the fact I am using the function twice that it isn't working?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try like `<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode here]"); ?> ` this??
Share more details. can you share actual code?

Comment: I have added screenshots

Comment: The double quotes are probably closing the `do_shortcode` too early. For each double quote within the brackets, change it to single quote... `do_shortcode("[ 'shortcode here' ]");`

Comment: Or vice versa, change the outer double quotes to single quotes. That looks like less work.

Comment: Will give that a try now. Thank you!

Comment: Despite changing the quotes it is still not working, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As @git-e-up mentioned in the comments. I highly suspect it's due to the syntax errors in your `do_shortcode` calls.

[image: code with notation]

See all these quotes that I've encircled in red?  They're all syntax errors as it terminates the quoted string prematurely.  Like @git-e-up mentioned in the comments, changing the outer quotes to single quotes is probably easier. (In case you weren't sure what they meant by that, I've encircled **some** of the outer quotes in green.)  In your editor, you want that entire string to be that same beige color in this case, like it is with the `show-team` shortcode.

Once you've accomplished that, if you're still running into problems:

I'd suggest running this file on the commandline through PHP with the `-l` (dash lower case L, for syntax linting) option set to make sure you've gotten all your syntax issues taken care of. Finally, if you're sure you've gotten your syntax errors cleaned up, search StackOverflow and ServerFault regarding PHP white screens for pointers on getting error messages to help you debug further.